# Time lag between date send in object from client side [GWT] to server side [Spring ]

Tags: java, spring, date, gwt

I have CellEditor where i want to edit date :

```
public interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<EditVO, ClassEditor> {
}

@UiField
DateBox date;

private final Driver driver;

@Inject
ClassEditor(Binder uiBinder,
              Driver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;


    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    driver.initialize(this);

    DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy);
    date.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(dateFormat));
}

@Override
public void edit(DossierEditVO object) {
    driver.edit(object);
}

@Override
public EditVO get() {
    EditVO object = driver.flush();
    if (!driver.hasErrors()) {
        return object;
    }
    return null;
}
```

i have Date in class EditVO, in Controller i have :

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
GetResult<Boolean> updateDossier(@RequestBody EditVO dossierEditVO) {
   //call service
   }
```

The problem that i have is when i select date that i want to edit for example : 11/10/2015, i get in client side with debug : Sun Oct 11 00:00:00 GMT+100 2015
and in server side i get : Sun Oct 10 23:00:00 UTC 2015. It's like a get a time tag of 2 hours between client side and server side.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify a time zone, Java will use system time zone when printing dates. Your client and your server have different time zones.

Comment: How can i change the GWT timezone?

Comment: For security reasons, you cannot change time zone of a browser, but you can specify a time zone when displaying a date - look at `DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: I already try with DateTimeFormat class, but it does not work it only changes the date format and not the timeZone. should I serialize the object or date that i want to transfer to server side?

Comment: You should use DateTimeFormat.format(date, timezone) method to display time in a desired time zone.

Comment: One typical approach is to save date objects as Long values (`date.getTime()`), and then create dates from these values and display them in desired time zones.

Comment: i send object as string on format dd/mm/yyyy (the problem was in hours o date ) and then i converted string to date